# Is it possible to create a c solution in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to build a c (not cpp or visual cpp) application with visual studio? I do not want to only build it via cmd line but have some kind of project/solution within visual studio.

I've programmed in high-level languages like c#, java, python, etc etc but have no idea of c/cpp. I want to start learning c (again: not cpp/visual cpp). But I would prefer using visual studio since I'm pretty comfortable with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with MSVC. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya98c175(v=vs.90).aspx) site:

> Give your files the `.c` extension, for example `mysource.c`. The Visual C++ compiler automatically assumes that files with the `.C` extension are `C` files and not `C++` files, and rejects `C++` syntax and keywords (such as `public`, `private`, and `class`).
>   `C++` files use the `.cpp` extension.
>   See the `/TC`, `/TP` compiler options for more information.

Comment: So I just create a win32 project and name my files `*.c`?

Comment: Create an "empty" project to avoid VS creating default files.